# Dotnet publish-iis exit with code 1. Project.json not found when using .csproj?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am migrated a NET Core 1.0 project with project.json file to Net Core 1.1 project with .csproj file. At the end of the .csproj file I have the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.Tools" Version="1.1.0-preview4-final" />
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools" Version="1.1.0-preview4-final" />
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.1.0-preview4-final" />
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.1.0-preview4-final" />        
</ItemGroup>  

<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />

<Target Name="Prepublish" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish" Condition=" '$(IsCrossTargetingBuild)' != 'true' ">
  <Exec Command="npm install" />
  <Exec Command="bower install" /> 
  <Exec Command="gulp clean" />
  <Exec Command="gulp build" />
</Target>  

<Target Name="Postpublish" AfterTargets="Publish" Condition=" '$(IsCrossTargetingBuild)' != 'true' ">    
  <Exec Command="dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder $(TargetDir) --framework $(TargetFrameworkIdentifier),Version=$(TargetFrameworkVersion)" />
</Target>
```

When publishing the project I get the error on dotnet publish-iis:

```
exited with code 1.
```

I tried to find the error and the only thing I found was:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\MVCProj\project.json'.
```

But why is it looking for the project.json file if I am using .csproj?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are still looking for the answer, I discovered that the publish-iis cli tools are no longer used.

https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/4855#issuecomment-263799301

You need to remove the reference to the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools` package and the whoe `Postpublish`Target from your .csproj file.